# Xml Transformation and Variable substitution doesn't work when both selected in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, variable-substitution

I have been working on the build and release pipelines for a while now, but ran into this issue lately

I am performing config transform on .net application. The issue i am running into is a bit strange .. Variable substitution doesn’t work if xml transformation is enabled too, but will work ONLY when variable substitution is enabled. I didn't knew this was possible, as per me Variable substitution would work after XML transformation is done. I want to use both the options. Like i want to transform the existing config file and then substitute the remaining values with pipeline variables & variable groups. That way i would have less involvement from other teams to get the transformation for all the values as i have a time crunch. Eventually would have everything transformed but for now i want to follow the above approach. The log does say Xml transformation and Variable substitution completed successful, but variable substitution doesn't happen.

Am i missing something very silly? Has anyone faced this kind of issue.

[image]

Comment: any pointers please? still stuck at this issue.

Comment: From the screenshot , it seems that you are using the `IIS web app deploy` task. If yes, you could check the `_temp `folder during  the process of deployment. The conversion happens in this folder. You could refer to the answer.  If there is any misunderstanding, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, `XML variable substitution` and `XML transformation` could work at the same time.

Here is the original web.config file:

[image]

Check the log, the transformation occurred in the `_temp` folder instead of the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` (e.g. I use deployment group to run the task, so the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) path is `C:\azagent\A18\_work\r4\a`).

[image]

In the temp folder, I noticed that the file has been transformed successfully.

[image]

If the object you deploy is a **folder**, then this transformation can **only** be found in the temp folder. After the deployment, the contents of this folder will be automatically deleted after deployment.

If the object you deploy is a **zip** file, in addition to the temp folder, a zip will be automatically generated in the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` path, and the web.config file in this zip is also successfully transformed.

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

Here are some details:

Files:(web.config and web.qa.config)

[image]

Web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PCWSUser" value="TheUserName" />
  </appSettings>
```

Web.qa.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="PCWSUser" value="TheUserNameQA" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Release Pipeline variables:

[image]

Task settings:

[image]

Summary: the `webpages:Version` is changed by variable substitution. The others are changed by xml transformation.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the response, This doesn't really say if the transformation happ due to xml or variable. Few quick questions. Did you select both the options in the pipeline i.e. xml and var and did you have the transform file in the same location i.e. web.qa.config etc ... can you specify which values were changed due to XML transformation and which ones were changed due to variable substitution.

Comment: Hi @AnsibleUser. Please check the update. I have shared some details about the your questions.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for clarity, the only difference i see is the variables in the config are mutually exclusive i.e.the keys cannot be present in both the locations i.e. transform and var. If they are, then transform one takes precedence. I was under assumption first transform happens and then it is overwritten by variable substitution. Will try that out. Thanks again Kevin.

Comment: Yes. You are right.  The XML transformation  runs before variable transformation . So if the variable is defined in xx.qa.config and variable, it will eventually be replaced by the value in variable.

Comment: I did debug runs and found parsing error .. unfortunately it doesn't tell the parsing error for web.config file ...It just  gives this error ...                                                  
 2020-08-14T23:46:56.6511657Z ##[debug]Detecting file encoding using BOM
2020-08-14T23:46:56.6712776Z ##[debug]Unable to parse file : D:\Non-Deploy\TFSAgentazagent\A3\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_34975992642936804\Web.config
2020-08-14T23:46:56.6713097Z ##[debug]Error: Incomplete document

Comment: I think i figured out the issue. The issue was due to CData tag in teh config file. After that was removed from Web.config as well as from the Transform config, both the options seems to be working. Will need to test more.